# How to configure Debugger in CLion?

Tags: c, clion, jetbrains-ide

I downloaded CLion to develop applications in both C and Rust. However, I cannot run the debugger because I haven't configured the toolchains yet. This is what I see:

[image: Settings page for Toolchains]

On the CLion docs and YouTube, they already have the environment setup beforehand. I don't know how to configure my CLion to debug programs. **I am using Linux**, so what are the packages I need to install and what are the steps I need to follow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should detect the standard toolchains (e.g. GCC, GDB, CMake, ...) automatically if you have installed them. So just installing them should be enough.

E.g. if you're using a Debian-based Linux distribution like Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt install gcc gdb cmake
```

Or on a Fedora-based distribution:

```
sudo dnf install gcc gdb cmake
```

Perhaps restart CLion if it doesn't detect them right away.

Comment: CLion did not detect it right away. I had to manually find the location of the executable files and set them. It works now, thanks!